# Почему возникает ошибка "'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'GET'"?

Tags: django, get, python-2.7

Знакомлюсь с `Django`, пытался получать `GET` запрос, но выдает ошибку.
Кто разбирается, помогите!

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError at /cyp
'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

Код:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View


def mydata(request):
    return request.GET['myreq']

class HomePageView(View):
    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        abc = mydata(request)
        return HttpResponse(abc)
```

Comment: Вы пропустили self в объявлении dispatch. Должно быть так `def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @godva спасибо! Исправил, все работает!